# How to write apps for the Apple Pencil?

Tags: ios, swift

how would I start writing apps for the pencil? Are there any APIs or SDKs for the Pencil itself?

Comment: Why all the hate? It's not so evident that there is no dedicated framework, and that there's nothing but a few new UITouch properties...

Comment: Why is this closed? There is very little info on the net about it. This is second question that i bumped into, about a vague topic, and it is closed.

Answer (score 6):

Apple has updated the UITouch class to support the Apple Pencil. New properties include force ( used with 3D Touch too ), altitude and azimuth, as well as a bit mask to check which property is or is not available.

Finally, there's also a new type property which will let you know if the UITouch instance represents Apple Pencil, a direct touch, or an indirect one (accessory).

Have a look at the docs for UITouch here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/